# Xcode 11.1 upgrade strangeness - main screen appearing as Modal View

Tags: ios, xcode11

I have (had) a perfectly working app thats published.

Recently I upgraded to Xcode 11.1 from Xcode 10 and now when I run the app instead of getting a splash screen then the main form appearing I get the main form appearing as a modal view and the splash screen going white and appearing as the main screen behind the modal view.

Presumably somethings changed in the framework that's now broken my app anyone any ideas as to what's changed so I can fix it?

Comment: I think you've meant Xcode 11.1, not 13 (and you mean iOS SDK 13 probably). I've changed that, feel free to revert it if I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iOS13 modal type defaults to `automatic`, often inferring `pageSheet`, you need to manually modify

```
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks that was (kind of the problem) I had a seque set up whose presentation was "Same as Destination" changing it to Full Screen fixes the probelm.